# Mocha.js : how to run some code after all tests are completed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

A typical MochaJS test, of course, includes `before` and `after` blocks where one can run a setup/teardown.

However, I would like to perform an additional teardown step after *all test files* are processed - to take into account any loose resources that individual teardowns may forget to delete.

How could I achieve that in MochaJS?

Answer (score 1):

Most recent Mocha's version (8.x) bring support for root hook plugin, which allow to do exactly what you need, if you running tests in serial mode. There is a good point to start: https://mochajs.org/#root-hook-plugins

Answer (score 0):

You can run `Mocha` [programmatically](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Using-Mocha-programmatically). The nice thing is that Mocha support events for the runner that exposes exactly what you need.

> mocha.run() returns a Runner instance which emits many events of interest.

```
 * Events:
 *   - `start`  execution started
 *   - `end`  execution complete
 ...
```